# How to copy each reported bug in JIRA to bugzilla

Tags: jira, bugzilla

I have a requirement to copy the each reported bug from JIRA to Bugzilla automatically and having super user previliges for both bug systems.

Comment: There is a feature for migration from other tracking systems, see [3.9. Migrating From Other Bug-Tracking Systems](http://bugzilla.readthedocs.io/en/5.0/installing/migrating.html?highlight=migrate)

Answer (score 0):

In Jira,Webhooks option is there in administaration page.With this option you will get the JSON information of the particular bug,With this information will post a bug in bugzilla using REST API's.